# How to get oauth access token data saved in database

Tags: python, django, oauth, django-authopenid

To be able to make `API` calls on behalf of the user who granted access to `django` app, I have done the following :

1. I have added the field below to the `UserAssociation` class in the `django-authopenid` models ([see link](https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel/blob/master/askbot/deps/django_authopenid/models.py) line 54) :

   ```
   data_access_token = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   ```
2. In the `complete_oauth1_signin` request in the `django-authopenid` views ([see link](https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel/blob/master/askbot/deps/django_authopenid/views.py) line 428) I have added :

   ```
   access_token_data = oauth._get_access_token_data()
   ```

   (Note: `_get_access_token_data` is from the `OAuthConnection` class in the [`util.py`](https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel/blob/master/askbot/deps/django_authopenid/util.py) line 1005).
3. and I have added:

   ```
   return finalize_generic_signin(
       request=request,
       user=user,
       user_identifier=user_id,
       login_provider_name=oauth_provider_name,
       link_token=access_token_data,
       redirect_url=next_url)
   ```
4. In addition, in the `create_authenticated_user_account` in the `views.py` (see link line 118), I have added :

   ```
   UserAssociation(
       openid_url = user_identifier,
       user = user,
       provider_name = login_provider_name,
       data_access_token = link_token
       last_used_timestamp = timezone.now()
   ).save()
   ```

Please tell me what action shall I do to be able to store `oauth` access token data.

Comment: after the oauth flow processing, the openid_url is saved in the user association table but the access token data is not stored in this table

Comment: @ironfroggy do you have this customization of django-authopenid?